# Wordpress Import WXR

Tags: wordpress

I have tried multiple times to import my old blog hosted on wordpress to my custom domain site running wordpress, however, everytime I try importing the file,it ends up with a blank screen, I have checked the upload folder to contain the same but it is not showing up in my website. **Please help**.
My site is hosted on a parallel plesk shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that WordPress theme is not applied for this website.
Try to do following:

- Open Wordpress Toolkit and scan for installations.
- Press Themes section on desired website.
- Apply one of listed themes.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your file is having trouble uploading completely.  If you have php 5 or newer running try to create a file called .user.ini and place it in your Wordpress installation folder with the following in it.

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
memory_limit = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

You can also add this to your php.ini file or if you do not have access to the php.ini file create a new file called php5.ini and upload it to the root of your Wordpress install with the above in it.  Good luck.